# Creating proportional symbol map in ArcMap based on two different layers (polygon and points) using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, symbology

I am using ArcGIS and I have a shapefile of Mongolia soums (equivalent to counties), and for each soum there is a sample size attribute associated with it. However, I also have a list of five cities with lat/lon; those cities also have a sample size attribute.

I want to create a proportional symbol map based on the sample size of both the soums and the cities, but I don't know how to combine points and polygons and draw proportional symbols collectively.  I don't really have a way to join these two datasets since they don't have anything in common. Is there a good way to do this?

An alternative I have is to create shapefiles for these cities, but I suppose that would be even more difficult?

For example, the CSV file is an example data:
[image]

I want to create a circle on top of each entry (either city or soum), the circle size represents the sample size column.  I have a set of shapefiles that are all the Soums, but there are a coupe of entries that are cities instead of Soums, I have the lat/lon but not a polygon, how would I do it in ArcGIS so that I can make a proportional symbol map with the following data?

As an example output, I would like something as the following, except that it's Mongolia and that the symbols are drawn based on both polygons and city coordinates in ArcGIS

[image: (Example image from M.Bostock)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this I would:

1. Create a point feature class from the centroids of your polygons
2. Create a city points feature class from the CSV coordinates
3. Append your city points into that polygon centroids point feature class
4. Use proportional symbols on the appended point feature class